# Getting 403 "Insufficient Permission" from gmail-api using get_application_default from a gce instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, gmail-api

I have the gmail api activated and I am on an instance with "full API access to all Google Cloud services". When I run the following from the instance:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
```

I get:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

I have tried several other gmail-api calls and this is always the response.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts) method.

Comment: working through the docs: `from oauth2client.gce import AppAssertionCredentials
    scope ='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope)
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)
    service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()`
gets the same result 403